# std::is_convertible template implementation

Tags: c++, templates

I came across [an implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) of `std::is_convertible` and was confused on why they would test for returnability. Below is an excerpt of the total implementation. Why cast a nullptr to pointer to a function returning type T? Is there an example of a type that is not returnable?

```
template<class T>
auto test_returnable(int) -> decltype(
    void(static_cast<T(*)()>(nullptr)), std::true_type{}
);
template<class>
auto test_returnable(...) -> std::false_type;
```

Answer (score 4):

This tests to see if the type T is valid to return from a function via SFINAE and returns true_type or false_type depending on the result.

For example, functions have types yet cannot be returned from functions (though pointers and references to them can be)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions

Comment: In the second sentence, do you mean functions **are** types?

Comment: If the return type is being checked for functions, does it mean I can check for `not std::is_function<T>::value` instead of return type? @xaxxon

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and supply a specific example that is not returnable: 
`decltype(test_returnable<void()>(0))::value  // false`

   Note that the pointer (or reference) to function is returnable: 
`decltype(test_returnable<void(*)()>(0))::value  // true`